# Problems setting up/using dwww

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have installed dwww and I am able to display the home page ("ubuntudesktop/dwww"). When I try to access specific documents most of the time an error is displayed. Example trying to access bc man page displays "The requested URL /cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/man/man1/bc.1.gz was not found on this server.". From the Debian Documentation Menu , when I try to access the "install-docs Manual" I get the following error "The requested URL /cgi-bin/dwww/usr/share/doc/doc-base/install-docs.html was not found on this server.". I haven't been able to find documentation that helps me fix the problem. Any suggestions on how to get dwww too to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dwww/+bug/1243839

Comment: Still relevant on 20.04 LTR

Answer (score 4):

The workaround solution for this problem can be found in the bug-report for the issue.

As posted by user rememberthemer:

> I've had the same issue and have found the solution.
>
> The cgi module in apache is not enabled by default or is improperly enabled.
>
> Enabling cgi resolves this issue.
>
> You can use the apache tools:
>
> `sudo a2enmod cgi`
>
> `sudo service apache2 restart`
>
> This really should be enabled by default - anyone installing dwww will expect it to work.

Comment: Here we are 6.5 years later (Ubuntu 20.04) and the issue still exists... enabling cgi and restarting apache does not work.

Comment: @TheGeeko61 I bet I know the fix. Is your GPU a Nvidia, by chance?

Comment: @NateT: I use an AMD on a laptop.  I don't think it has an nvidia GPU - I know that  system/status reports that I've gottewn refer to AMD CPU as well as AMD graphics built into the CPU.